# how to set two diffrent launcher name and icon in one app (android)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

i am working on an app in witch i am performing two launches from one installation. my both launcher are working fine for there separate individual tasks.

but my problem is: i am getting same name or same icon for both launcher.
i want two different icon and name for both launchers.

this is my **manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Start Wallpaper App -->

    <application
        android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FreeWallTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


<!--         End Wallpaper App -->

        <!-- Start Crop App -->

        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.CropWallpaper.FolderListScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|fontScale|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.CropWallpaper.ImageListScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|fontScale|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.CropWallpaper.MyPrefScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|fontScale"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.CropWallpaper.CropWallpaper"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|fontScale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:process=":CropWallpaper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--End Crop App -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#icon) says, you can provide `android:icon` attribute in `activity` tag for the two launchers. It will override that provided in `application` tag. And for the name of launcher, just set `android:label` to different string resource.

Currently you only provide an Icon in `application` tag and `android:label` for the two activities are the same resource, so you will see same icon and same label.